Ternery Operator in Tailwind with React
I passed a useState in another module. I want to create a toggle button for dark mode and light mode. Now when the use state changes I want to change the background. I want to do this with a ternary operator. I tried to put in Tailwind $ and {} but I think I made some mistakes with the quotes.
<div className='h-screen' ${lightMode ? 'bg-white' : 'bg-[#2b2c37]'} 'w-1 /5 text - white border - r border - [#515258] flex flex - col gap - 8 px - 5 py - 5` >

this is the line.  LightMode is a UseState and false by default.
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react';



export default function Sidebar(props) {
  const { allboards, activeBoard, setActiveBoard, handleclickPopUpBoard, lightMode, toggle } = props;





  return (
    <div className='h-screen' ${lightMode ? 'bg-white' : 'bg-[#2b2c37]'} 'w-1 /5 text - white border - r border - [#515258] flex flex - col gap - 8 px - 5 py - 5` >
      < img src = "public\assets\logo-light.svg" />
        <h1 className='text-2xl text-[#808ca0]'>All boards </h1>

  {
    allboards.map((board) => (

      <div
        key={board}
        onClick={() => setActiveBoard(board)}
        className={board === activeBoard ? ' bg-[#635ec5]  p-2 rounded' : 'text-[#808ca0]'}
      >
        <img src="public\assets\icon-board.svg" />
        {board}
      </div>
    ))
  }
      <button className='px-4 py-2 bg-[#635ec5] rounded-lg' onClick={() => handleclickPopUpBoard()}>
        Create new board
      </button>
      <button className='w-16 -h-16 rounded-full bg-yellow-400' onClick={() => toggle()}>LIGHT</button>

    </div >
  );
}



What you've pasted has multiple syntax errors. Fix those first...
